# How to bind multiline textbox to bindingList<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, binding, textbox

How can I bind textboxt text to BindingList?
I want so that when I add/change/remove string from that BindingList my TextBox will update.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Create a single string with line breaks from the List

```
 stringbuilder sb = new stringbuilder();   
 foreach (string s in lstring) sb.AppendLine(s);
```

Comment: I want to bind it. Not display once. I want textbox to change automaticly when something changes in the list<string>

Comment: Then re-run that code and rebind when something changes in List<String>

Comment: Really a down vote on post 4 months old.  Man / woman up and state what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use BindingSource class to bind a String to a textbox. All you need is to bind the textbox with BindingSource object, whose data source is the string you want to use.

```
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
BindingSource stringBindingSource;
string x = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";

stringBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text",stringBindingSource,"Length",true));
stringBindingSource.DataSource = x;
```